# TIC SSL Trust Error while accessing data from https url

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried to access data from a https url by following.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let stringURL = "https://192.168.104.91:8443/update_info.xml"
        let url = URL(string: stringURL)

        var data:Data? = nil

        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

But i am getting following error.

```
2018-03-21 12:49:35.529949+0600 AppName[704:205346] TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x1c0171a00]: 3:0
2018-03-21 12:49:35.541223+0600 AppName[704:205346] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2018-03-21 12:49:35.541283+0600 AppName[704:205346] Task <7D4A1063-B946-4588-830A-CE73AF5B4995>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9813])
2018-03-21 12:49:35.541771+0600 AppName[704:205344] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202
The file “update_info.xml” couldn’t be opened.
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have u resolved it?

Comment: still can't resolve the problem. Can you help ?